# Jquery hover bug?

Tags: jquery, hover

I used jquery hover to show item detail then user hovers over item on this page - dev.oyehabla.com The problem is that then mouse leaves the item the details must hide but sometimes they remain... Is it a jquery bug or i'm doing something wrong?
I use this code:

```
jQuery('#big_container .item-image').hover(function(){
   var $opt = $(this);
   $item_id = $opt.attr("id");
   $post_id = $item_id.split('-');
   jQuery('#'+$item_id + ' .media_block .post-detail').show();
   console.log($item_id + 'mouseover')
},function(){
   var $opt = $(this);
   $item_id = $opt.attr("id");
   $post_id = $item_id.split('-');
   jQuery('#'+$item_id + ' .media_block .post-detail').hide();
   console.log($item_id + 'mouseout')    
});
```

Comment: Please post a complete example, including the HTML. If you can create a jsFiddle too that would be great.

Comment: as a side note, since you are just show/hide, you don't need stop()

Comment: Here is the site in action: dev.oyehabla.com

Comment: actually it looks like you don't even need jquery to show/hide

Comment: Mouse events have always been sketchy using JavaScript.  You should probably have div's be shown/ hidden on mouse over inside the CSS rather than using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, i removed the stop()

Comment: Thanks Dropped.on.Caprica, i'll try css

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using CSS rather than jQuery for this, especially if you're just showing/ hiding div's.  Try this first:

```
$('#big_container .item-image').hover(function(){
   var $opt = $(this);
   $opt.find('.post-detail').show();
},function(){
   var $opt = $(this);
   $opt.find('.post-detail').hide();
});
```

This may fix your issue.  A better version using CSS:

```
#big_container .item-image .post-detail {
  display: none;
}

#big_container .item-image:hover .post-detail {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm interested, which one worked for you?  Did you use the CSS or jQuery fix?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the whole function.. just use this part

```
jQuery('#big_container .item-image').hover(function(){
   var $opt = $(this);
   $item_id = $opt.attr("id");
   $post_id = $item_id.split('-');
   jQuery('#'+$item_id + ' .media_block .post-detail').stop().show();
   console.log($item_id + 'mouseover')
});
```